# Error HH404: File @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/exstentions/ERC20Capped.sol

Tags: compiler-errors, smartcontracts, cryptocurrency, erc20

I'm using visual studio code and I'm trying to make my first crypto token so I'm new to all this coding and everything but I'm following a tutorial for a ERC20 token and im stuck on npx hardhat compile because every time i do it i get the error Error HH404:File@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/exstentions/ERC20Capped.sol
ive look everywhere for a solution and nothing works could someone help please?

the youtube video link is: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gc7e90MHvl8

i tried following the youtube video but it didnt go well